# How do i print certain items in a list based on user input in python?

Tags: python

So far the user is supposed to enter their name account number and balance which gets put into list. then I ask for them to input their account number and im supposed to print out their specific number from the list instead of the whole list but cant get it to work.

---

```
customers = list()
acctnum = list()
balance= list()

count = 0
while count != 2: 
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    customers.append(name)
    num = int(input("Enter account number: "))
    acctnum.append(num)
    bal = input("Enter Current Balance:$ ")
    print()
    balance.append(bal)
    count = count + 1

print(customers)
print(acctnum)
print(balance)


personal = int(input("Enter account number: "))
print(personal)
if personal in acctnum:

   print(acctnum)
```

Comment: Please explain what "can't get it to work" means.

Comment: you are printing the entire list of acctnum. instead print that specific element of acctnum 
`if personal in acctnum: print(personal)`

Answer (score 0):

I find dictionaries are useful in applications like this:

```
accounts = {}

for x in range(2): 
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    num = int(input("Enter account number: "))
    bal = input("Enter Current Balance: $")
    accounts[num] = {"name": name, "balance": bal}
    print()

for k, v in accounts.items():
    print(v["name"] + "'s account " + str(k) + " has $" + v["balance"])

personal = int(input("Enter account number: "))
if personal in accounts:
    print("Hello, " + accounts[personal]["name"] + " you have $" + accounts[personal]["balance"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The data right now is stored in independent lists. You would have to implement using an associative data type such as dictionaries (that are implemented in Python).

Comment: You don't necessarily "have to", but keeping track of indexes between the lists will result in more headaches than it's worth.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I meant storage in independent lists would make retrieval and storage a bit tedious. The use of dictionaries would be a more "natural" approach.